# how to integrate Bonjour in Android Application

Tags: android, bonjour

```
can anybody have any idea how to integrate Bonjour in Android Application.
```

any help will be appreciative.
thanks a lot.

Comment: Helps to use the correct name. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+zeroconf

Answer (score 0):

you can start with the mDNSResponder package in the github, it contains an implementation for bonjour broswer.